# Terraform: unableto deploy postgress 15 using azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server resource

Tags: azure, terraform, devops

Postgres 15 is available as a version option when creating 'Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Flexible Server'.   However, when i try to do so using terraform it's complaining that support only up to version 14 is supported.  Is there a way around this?

```
resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" "default" {
  name                   = "${var.name_prefix}-server"
  resource_group_name    = azurerm_resource_group.db_rg.name
  location               = azurerm_resource_group.db_rg.location
  version                = "15"
  delegated_subnet_id    = module.vn.subnet_ids[0]
  private_dns_zone_id    = azurerm_private_dns_zone.default.id
  zone                   = "1"
  storage_mb             = 32768
  sku_name               = "GP_Standard_D2s_v3"
  backup_retention_days  = 7

  depends_on = [azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link.default]
}
```

The above will cause the following error when i do a an apply:

```
│ Error: expected version to be one of [14 11 13 12], got 15
│
│   with azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server.default,
│   on main.tf line 47, in resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" "default":
│   47:   version                = "15"
│
```

Comment: which terraform provider version you're using? Latest one ?

Comment: i have: version = "~>3.17.0"
i see u posted a potential work around.i will try and let you know. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to deploy Postgres 15 using the azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server resource and I was able to provision the resource successfully.

There is a way around this. As you mentioned, PostgreSQL 15 is available as a version option when creating an Azure Database for PostgreSQL - Flexible Server, but it is still in public preview and is not yet supported by Terraform. The error message you are getting is because Terraform is trying to create a PostgreSQL 15 server, but the version is not supported.

For this make sure the terraform provider is updated to date or at least to version **>=3.53.0** when the terraform module starts supporting the version

For flexibility, I was using the latest version of the provider.

**My Terraform Configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {} 
} Latest Version 3.71.0

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
    name = "v-bolliv"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "vkdemo-vn"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "vkdemo-sn"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
  service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Storage"]
  delegation {
    name = "fs"
    service_delegation {
      name = "Microsoft.DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers"
      actions = [
        "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action",
      ]
    }
  }
}
resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "example" {
  name                = "vk.postgres.database.azure.com"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link" "example" {
  name                  = "vkVnetZone.com"
  private_dns_zone_name = azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.name
  virtual_network_id    = azurerm_virtual_network.example.id
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server" "example" {
  name                   = "vk-psqlflexibleserver"
  resource_group_name    = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location               = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  version                = "15"
  delegated_subnet_id    = azurerm_subnet.example.id
  private_dns_zone_id    = azurerm_private_dns_zone.example.id
  administrator_login    = "psqladmin"
  administrator_password = "H@Sh1CoR3!"
  zone                   = "1"
  
  storage_mb = 32768

  sku_name   = "GP_Standard_D4s_v3"
  depends_on = [azurerm_private_dns_zone_virtual_network_link.example]

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Ref: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/21934

Comment: thanks for this.  there were two changes needed.  first as you suggested i bumped the provider  version to ">=3.53.0".
The second was to change collation for resource azurerm_postgresql_flexible_server_database from "en_US.UTF8" to "en_US" only - it didnt like the former